# Scheme Programming: Contract Violation Error in Function when interacting with List

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I am instructed to perform the following:
( insertBag List Item ) -- return a new bag that represents the result of inserting the given item in the given list

```
;Function Two: insertBag
;@Param: List, Item
;@Return: The new bag that represents the result of
;inserting the given item in the given list.
;Important Note: There are two Helper functions for insertBag
;Helper Function One: newPair
;Helper Function Two: addPair 

(define (insertBag List Item)

 ;Check if we have an Empty List
 (if (null? List)
  (newPair Item)
   
   (if (string=? (car(car List)) Item)
    (cons (addPair (car List)) (cdr List))
    (cons (car List) (insertBag(cdr List) item))
   )
 )
)

;Helper Function One: newPair

(define (newPair Item)
 (cons Item 1)
)

;Helper Function Two: addPair

(define (addPair List)
 (cons (car List) (+ 1 (cdr List)))
)


;Test Run Case for insertBag
(insertBag '(("a".2)("d".1)("c".3)) "a"); Input for A
```

However, I get the following error:

```
; +: contract violation
;   expected: number?
;   given: '(0.2)
;   argument position: 2nd
; [,bt for context]
```

Please note that I was instructed to not use lambda. I would appreciate some help!
Thank you!
>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the sample input, you *must* write spaces between the dots: `'("a".2)` is a list with `"a"` and `0.2` as its elements, whereas `'("a" . 2)` is a `cons` pair with `"a"` in the `car` part and `2` in the `cdr` part. With this little change, your code will work as expected:

```
(insertBag '(("a" . 2) ("d" . 1) ("c" . 3)) "a")
```

Comment: Hello @Óscar López, first thank you for your help regarding case "a", but when I do it for case "d" or case "c" I get the following error:
; item: undefined;
;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
;   in module: top-level
; [,bt for context]
>

Comment: @rockyDodgers in the last line of `insertBag ` you wrote `item` instead of `Item`, fix that and it'll work ;)

Comment: I was about to comment that when I looked at my code and saw that error =)